# how to find a value based on a formula in a column and based on the finding result have to update the if condition

Tags: vba

i am getting error while executing the below code in my macro file. Please help me to fix. The intention is that i need to add a new column everyday while refreshing a pivot. If it was already done the sheet will have to look into it based on the columns heading from H1 and show a message stating the sheet was already refreshed. If no value found, it will have to execute my another code to insert a new column.

```
Sub Check_Column() 
Dim rng As Range,cell As Range,search As String

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns("H:ZZ") ' here i wants to use the endcilumn till the last non blank column' 
search = [WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)].Formula 
Set cell = rng.Find(What:=search, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
If cell Is Nothing Then 
    Call AddHeader 
Else 
    MsgBox ("Data already refreshed for today")
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Plase, try the next updated code:

```
Sub Check_Column()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, cell As Range, lastCol As String, search As String

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastCol = Split(sh.cells(2, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Address, "$")(1)

 Set rng = sh.Range("H:" & lastCol)
 search = "=WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)"
 Set cell = rng.Find(What:=search, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

 If cell Is Nothing Then
    Call AddHeader
 Else
    Select Case Weekday(cell.value, vbMonday)
         Case 1:
            MsgBox "Monday"
         Case 2:
            MsgBox "Tuesday"
         Case 3:
            MsgBox "Wednesday"
         Case 4:
            MsgBox "Thursday"
         Case 5:
            MsgBox "Fiday" 'do whatever you need for this day...
    End Select
    
    MsgBox ("Data already refreshed for today")
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @SRK: Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: thanks for your guidance. Here, my issue is the formula =WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1), will get a random value everyday. so, I want to write an IF condition based on the result. Eg. if the value is Friday, i need to do an operation else if it is a Monday, i wish to run another operation. please suggest an appropriate way.

Comment: @SRK: Is there the formula "=WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)" in more than one cell of column H:H? If not, my code will return the cell you need. Then, you can use the cell value to do whatever you need. If this is the case I can adapt the code to show you how to use it, even if you did not said anything in your question about this aspect... Anyhow, I will adapt the code...

Comment: @SRK: Please, test the updated code. After finding the cell with the searched formula, it returns the week day.

Comment: @SRK:  Still alive? Didn't the code adaptation ring any bell, in terms of what you requested?